# Expression expected

Tags: java

Решил найти как использовать метод из одного класса в другом, нашел вот такое:

```
private Class Name = new Class();
```

Испробовал у себя. Из класса Handle нужно использовать метод EntityNameRussian в классе Manage. В классе Manage вбиваю

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(Main);
```

Выдаёт "Handler (Main) in Handler cannot be applied to ()".
Попробовал указать так

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Main);
```

После этого ошибка Expression expected. Сразу извиняюсь если где-нибудь дико туплю, в джаве недавно. Как это можно решить?

Comment: `Handler` - что это такое?

Comment: Из вашего вопроса не понятно ровным счетом ничего. Опишите что вы хотите сделать. Добавьте свой код, по одной строчке ничего не понятно.

Comment: Handler - это public class, в нём есть public void EntityNameRussian. Мне нужно этот public void использовать в другом классе - public class Manage. Как я пытался это сделать и какую ошибку выдало я описал выше. Не знаю как еще подробнее это описать

Comment: Кто такой Main?

Comment: `Main` - что это такое?

Comment: Main главный класс, public class Main extends JavaPlugin

Comment: И зачем название класса `Main` передается в конструктор `Handler`?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы использовать любой метод с известной нам сигнатурой, можно пойти через передачу ссылки на ф-ю:

```
class MyMath{
    public static int factorial(int n){
        if(n <= 1){
            return 1;
        }
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}
class factorialAnyAlgorithmCalculator{
    Function<Integer, Integer> factorial;

    public factorialAnyAlgorithmCalculator(Function<Integer, Integer> factorial){
        this.factorial = factorial;
    }

    public Integer getFactorial(Integer n) {
        return factorial.apply(n);
    }
}
```

Тест:

```
System.out.println(new factorialAnyAlgorithmCalculator(MyMath::factorial).getFactorial(4));
```

Вывод:

> 24

А по теме - вы должны написать `Main.class`. Запись:

```
Class class1 = Main.class;
```

Верна, запись же:

```
Class class1 = Main;
```

Неверна.